# EWS Set EmailMessage.Body.Text error

Tags: .net, vb.net, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have the following code to simply add text to an email:

```
msg = New EmailMessage(Service)
With msg
    .From = New EmailAddress(Config("OutSender"))
    .ToRecipients.Add(New EmailAddress(Config("OutRecip")))
    .Subject = Config("OutSubject")

    .Load(New PropertySet(ItemSchema.Body))
    .Body.Text = Config("protMarking")
    .Send()
End With
```

I get the error:

`You must load or assign this property before you can read its value`

on this line:

`.Body.Text = New MessageBody(Config("protMarking"))`

Which is why I tried to load the body property on this line:

`.Load(New PropertySet(ItemSchema.Body))`

However I'm now getting this error:

`This operation can't be performed because this service object doesn't have an Id`

After extensive googling and a lot of looking at my code I cant figure it out. I'm not sure why the new email message doesn't have an ID?

**NOTE:** `Service` is call to a property that returns the ews service. I have check that this is working properly.

Answer (score 3):

You should just set the `Body` property (not `Body.Text`)

The call to `Load` is not necessary in your case. For reference though, it isn't working as you haven't yet created the email message on the service. That only happens when you get to `Send` (which should probably be `SendAndSaveCopy()`

```
msg = New EmailMessage(Service)
With msg
    .From = New EmailAddress(Config("OutSender"))
    .ToRecipients.Add(New EmailAddress(Config("OutRecip")))
    .Subject = Config("OutSubject")
    .Body = Config("protMarking")
    .SendAndSaveCopy()
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

using @PaulG answer and some trial and error work prior to that, this was my solution.

```
msg = New EmailMessage(Service)
With msg
    .From = New EmailAddress(Config("OutSender"))
    .ToRecipients.Add(New EmailAddress(Config("OutRecip")))
    .Subject = Config("OutSubject")
    .Body = New MessageBody(Config("protMarking"))
    .SendAndSaveCopy()
End With
```

with this line being the major change/fix:

```
.Body = New MessageBody(Config("protMarking"))
```